# Firebase Hosted Sites issued to the wrong url

Tags: firebase, ssl

I have two sites hosted on firebase. Browsers accessing either site are reporting "This site can't provide a secure connection".

The ssl certificates my sites are issued to gautiervanrossom.com and besworth.io respectively.  I don't know anything about these entities.

How can I reset my firebase ssl to the correct url?

Comment: Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#ssl-provisioning

Comment: SSL certs are provisioned automatically.  If they aren't working the way you expect, [contact Firebase support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact).